# Setting a Zend_Form_Element_Text as not required?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I'm new to Zend Framework and I want to validate the user input of the **optional** form field `$start_date` with a regex. The Problem is that I'm not able to set this Zend_Form_Element_Text as not required, whereby I can't send all form values to the DB as long as there are no inputs for this date. I tried `->setAllowEmpty()` and `->setRequired()`.

The PHP Code looks like:

```
$start_date = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('start_date');
$start_date->setLabel('start_date')
    ->addFilter('StripTags')
    ->addFilter('StringTrim');
$start_date->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Errors',
    array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'class' => 'element'))
    ));
$start_date->addValidator('regex', false, array('/((\d{2})|(\d))\/((\d{2})|(\d))\/((\d{4})|(\d{2}))/'));
$start_date->setAttribs(array('class'=>'eingabe nospace', 'pattern'=>'((\d{2})|(\d))\/((\d{2})|(\d))\/((\d{4})|(\d{2}))', 'title'=>'Format: dd.mm.yyyy'));
```

Thanks!

Comment: What validation error do you get?

Comment: The validation works fine, the problem is that this field has to be optional. At the moment I can't send the form to the DB without a value for $start_date. So I'm looking for a solution to set $start_date as not required

Comment: I understand the problem, but elements are not required by default. I asked what validation error you were getting to see if it is the regex validator that's preventing the form from being submitted, or something else.

Comment: Regex validator wasn't the problem. Found it in my phtml where all values are getting checked if they're required.

Comment: $start_date->setRequired(false);